# how to make a select query to match a word with an unknown suffix?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For this query:

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE name LIKE '% testt %' OR name LIKE '% tests %';

Tell me please how make select where will be search word `test` + one unknown symbol on end word?

example rows:

```
Hello tests Words
Hello tested Words
Hello testing Words
```

result should get row `Hello tests Words`

Comment: And SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE name LIKE '%test_' does not work?

Comment: Is space one of unknown characters? I mean if there are two spaces after `test`, should it be selected or not? ex: `'Hello tests'` + `'[2 spaces]'` +  `'Words'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the _ symbol. It matches any ONE character, where as % matches any length of symbols.

```
WHERE name LIKE '% test_ %'
```